# Which type of terminal emulator installed in my ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: command-line

How to find which type of terminal emulator installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: The default terminal emulator used by standard Ubuntu with Unity desktop is `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 2):

**Xterm** and **Gnome-terminal**. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> + `gnome-terminal` / `xterm`.

**Bash** (Bourne-again shell) is the shell/command processor which these terminal uses.